# What font to use in a tutorial?

Tags: formatting

I'm elaborating a tutorial/guide about the software I used on my thesis. 
The tutorial and the thesis won't be part of the same document. So, I was thinking about using other than times/arial. 
Any sugestions?
Also, any design sugestions? I think the document looks very plain.

Comment: Also see [What kind of design freedom can you permit yourself in academic writing?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34869/what-kind-of-design-freedom-can-you-permit-yourself-in-academic-writing)

Comment: Also, why use Times/Arial in anything (unless you are required to do so)? They are among the most boring and overused fonts in existence.

Comment: Thanks! I also think they are quite boring, unfortunately I'm required to use one of them in my thesis, @Wrzlprmft!